# POD type with constructors but no aggregate initialization

Tags: c++, struct, default-constructor, aggregate-initialization

I'm confused about POD types in C++
I have these `struct HSV`and `struct RGB`  which is an accumulation of values to build a Color:

```
struct HSV
{
    int hue;
    int saturation;
    int value;
};

struct RGB
{
    // RGB(void) = default;
    // RGB(HSV const& hsv) { };
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
};
```

I can initialize a `struct RGB` with a C-like aggregate initialization like so:

```
RGB a = {.red=55, .green=125};
```

However when I uncomment the additional constructor to build a `struct RGB` with a `struct HSV` and the `default`ed default constructor, aggregate initialization doesn't work anymore

It will still tell me I have a POD on my hands however:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha;
std::cout << std::is_standard_layout<RGB>::value << '\n'; // true
std::cout << std::is_trivial<RGB>::value << '\n';  // true
std::cout << std::is_pod<RGB>::value << '\n';  // true
```

Can I use C-style aggregate initialization while having a transforming constructor like I have, or is that impossible?

EDIT: I was just notified that this is a `clang` extension (and seems to be possible with the VS Compiler as well). But I still wonder if it is possible, with `clang` at least.

Comment: C++ does not have designated initializers in the way C does. Your code isn't actually valid C++.

Comment: You're right, I just read that it is a clang extension